# Flutter Firestore How to do Dynamic Query?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
var searchRef = _firestore
        .collection("vehicles")
        .where("models.plane", isEqualTo: "true")
        .where("models.bus", isEqualTo: "true");
```

In this query method I can query multiple value but I want to do this dynamically. If the user enters the plane, I want to query the plane or if the user enters the plane and the bus, I want to query the plane and the bus, or if the user enters the plane, bus and sports car, I want to query the plane, bus and sports car. That is, the number of variables to be queried and the  variables will vary from user to user.

How can I convert this code to dynamic code.

**My Firebase Documents**

[Vehicle1 Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFIiy.png)

[Vehicle2 Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mciv.png)

[Vehicle3 Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQAbZ.png)

Comment: maybe call [where](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html) inside some loop?

Comment: I tried but I couldn't find a correct method. Can you post a dynamica-transformed version of this code with the method you said?

Comment: `Query query = _firestore..collection("vehicles");

loop {
  query = query.where(...);
}
` - this is pseudocode: you need to replace `...` with actual data based on current loop iteration, i hope you got the idea

Comment: You can create a query with all your parameters and you can avoid some parameter in query by passing null value. e.g. if you want to search for plane and bus, give value of place and bus and leave sports car null. This gonna work.

Comment: If you get query error then you have to create a index for this query which using multiple where conditions. For that you will received one link in console log. Click on that link and index will create automatically.